# Traversing promises in Q

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, future, promise, q

In Scala I can take a list of values, map a future-returning function across them, and get back a future that will collect the values of those futures into a list (or fail with the first error). More concretely:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def doSomething(i: Int): Future[Int] = future(i + 1) // Not really doing much.

val incremented = Future.traverse(List(1, 2, 3))(doSomething)
```

In this case the result will just be the incremented list:

```
scala> incremented.onSuccess { case xs => println(xs) }
List(2, 3, 4)
```

I could alternatively create a list of futures and then turn them into a future containing the same result:

```
val incremented = Future.sequence(List(1, 2, 3).map(doSomething))
```

This will give me the same thing, but it creates an extra intermediate collection and is a little more noisy.

I want to do something like this with promises in [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/), and it looks like `Q.all` is more or less `sequence`:

```
function doSomething(i) { return Q.fcall(function () { return i + 1; }); }

Q.all([1, 2, 3].map(doSomething)).then(function (xs) { console.log(xs) })
```

Is there a way for me to write a more `traverse`-like version? It's such a basic operation that it seems like there must be a way to do it, but this is my first afternoon with Q and I'm still working through all the overloads of `fcall` and friends.

Comment: @LeeMeador: Q is a JavaScript library—I'm just giving Scala code to demonstrate what I want to do.

Comment: You did notice that JavaScript (and the Q library) is not executing parallel, but only asynchronous? It only helps when `doSomething` is an asynchronous task (with callbacks and some parallel things running in th background).

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer to your question, but AngularJS uses an extremely reduced version of Q ([$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)), so there you definitely have to implement this behavior yourself.

Here's one approach:

```
var traverse = function(fn /*values*/) {
  var values = _.rest(arguments);
  var promises = _.map(values, fn);
  return $q.all(promises);
};
```

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PGp7QbQYMjOknJwSEn8E

Or with separate parameter lists as in Scala:

```
  var traverse = function(/*values*/) {
    var values = arguments;
    return function(fn) {
      var promises = _.map(values, fn);
      return $q.all(promises);  
    }
  };
```

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/pWoGGaZobbx61tAmUWr9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise Chaining + Static values (instead of promises) for methods and do something like:

```
Q.all([1,2,3])
    .then(function(xs) {
      return _(xs).map(doSomething) 
    })
    .then(function(xs) {
      console.log(xs);
    });
```

If you want a traverse function like that one, you can easily implement it yourself

Hope it helps!

Comment: The function passed to `.then()` should be returning a value. You should return `xs` in your second function.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand, and this doesn't seem to do what I want—it looks like it returns a future that will contain a list of futures?

Comment: @idbehold Actually, there's no need for the then to return something, it's just if you want to convert this promise to a promise of another thing, but in this case there's no need.

Comment: @TravisBrown yeah, that's exactly it, and you're right, that's not exactly what you need, you could convert that to an array of primises with Q.all([Q.when(1), Q.when(2), Q.when(3)] and then continue as it was but it's too verborragic.